# IntelliJ JavaDoc - error - cannot read Input length = 1

Tags: intellij-idea, character-encoding, windows-10, javadoc, windows-1252

I know there are plenty of questions about this problem, but no one of the solved it for me! I'm using the Community Edition of IntelliJ and I tried to run JavaDoc through the IDE. Everytime and it doesn't matter fo which file, I run JavaDoc I got the following output:

```
javadoc: error - cannot read Input length = 1
```

I already figured out, that it might be an encoding problem... I'm working on a *Windows 10* maschine. I already tried the following:

- [JavaDoc argfile encoding error](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000649644-Javadoc-argfile-encoding-error)
- Start the terminal from IntelliJ with `cmd.exe /K chcp 65001` instead of the default one `cmd.exe` to set the charset to UTF-8
- I also set the project's default charset through the IntelliJ settings to UTF-8 (See: [This Guide](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/))

The problem seems to be the `javadoc_args` file respectively the path to that file... The path is `C:\Users\Somebody Müller\AppData\Local\Temp\javadoc_args`. Also if I view the file from IntelliJ, all **ü** characters are replaced by an unknown symbol.

I know that I could generate the documentation through a maven plugin, but I would prefer to do it via the IntelliJ IDE...

*Could somebody identify the problem in detail and/or provide a solution or maybe parts of it?*

**EDIT**

[skomisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985643/skomisa) described the situation/behaviour in easy words:

> For me the **javadoc_args** file does not exist! I see it is named in the Javadoc window as an argument to **javadoc.exe**, and if I click the link its content is shown in a pop up window within Intellij IDEA, but if I check in File Explorer there is no such file. Is this the case for you as well? I have no idea how it gets generated. Also, I created a project in a folder named **Müller** and the **ü** was rendered as � within the popup window that showed the content of **javadoc_args**.

**UPDATE 04/12/2018**

As skomisa already commented, JetBrains plans to fix this bug in a future version, likely in version **2019.1 (Build 191.2458)**.

**UPDATE 22/02/2019**

I know this question is quite old but it seems to be still relevant. I didn't check up to now if JetBrains fixed the bug but a similar one occurred for me when I try to open an JavaFX fxml externally inside of the SceneBuilder. In another [post](https://superuser.com/a/986487) about renaming a Windows 10 user directory I found a possible workaround at least for Windows users! Just create an additional user directory without `ü` in the path and link to the existing one:

```
C:
CD\Users
MKLINK /J Müller Mueller
```

If you now uses the link as directory for project paths it should work fine.

Comment: [1] Which JDK version are you using? [2] Have you tried running that **javadoc.exe** command that is executed in the _Javadoc_ window from a _Command Prompt_ window instead? i.e. Outside of Intellij IDEA. [3] I can reproduce the problem with the bad Javadoc content. For me _ü_ is rendered as _Ã¼_ within the HTML documentation. Is that what you get as well? [4] I can't reproduce the _"Input length = 1"_ failure. [5] If I use OpenJDK 10 then **Tools > Generate JavaDoc...** fails with _"javadoc" finished with exit code -1073741790 (0xC0000022)_ [6] I am using ULTIMATE 2018.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: @skomisa Of course I tried it outside from IntelliJ... It works from command line and also generated through a maven plugin. Is the `javadoc_args` file stored in the `Temp` directory generated by IntelliJ or javadoc? Because I guess the encoding of that file is the problem... By the way I'm using the AdoptOpenJDK 11

Comment: OK. For me the **javadoc_args** file does not exist! I see it is named in the Javadoc window as an argument to **javadoc.exe**, and if I click the link its content is shown in a pop up window within Intellij IDEA, but if I check in File Explorer there is no such file. Is this the case for you as well? I have no idea how it gets generated. Also, I created a project in a folder named **Müller** and the **ü** was rendered as **�** within the popup window that showed the content of **javadoc_args**. I will test with AdoptOpenJDK 11 later.

Comment: @skomisa Yea exactly the behaviour of my IDE... I guess the file is temporary and is removed after usage. Okay thanks in advance!

Comment: I got an email from JetBrains that the bug I raised for this issue has been fixed in Build 191.2458, so the next release of Intellij IDEA (presumably 2019.1) should resolve your _"cannot read input..."_ problem.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you so much for your efforts

Comment: I got a further email from JetBrains stating that the problem has also been fixed in Build 183.4909. I am on the latest release of 2018.3 and the build number is 183.4588.61, so the fix is not there yet. It will presumably be included in a 2018.3 update in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to generate the Javadoc for a project in Intellij IDEA if the name of the path contains the character **ü** (u with umlaut). The workaround is to rename the project so that the project directory file path does not contain an umlaut.

To reproduce:

- Use the project wizard to create a trivial *Java Hello World* project where the root directory name contains **ü**. I used **Müller** for testing purposes.
- Ensure that the class for `main()` contains valid Javadoc documentation.
- Build and run the project to verify that there are no unexpected issues.
- Select **Tools > Generate Javadoc**, specify an empty **Output Directory** and click **OK**.
- Javadoc creation fails with the *error - cannot read Input length = 1* (shown below), and clicking the link to  **C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Temp\javadoc_args** shows that the **ü** in the file path is (mis)represented as �, which presumably is the cause of the Javadoc error.
- However, once the root directory is renamed from **Müller** to **Muller** (to remove the umlaut) the Javadoc creation works:

  [image: javadocWorks]
- As a sanity check, rename the project from **Muller** back to **Müller** to reintroduce the error:

  [image: javadocFails]

Notes:

- As noted in the comments, the **javadoc_args** file does not exist, and I see  no way to prevent its use during the Javadoc creation process.
- Having the project name as **Müller** is not an issue; it's having **ü** within the project's file path that causes the problem.
- Environment: Windows 10 + Intellij IDEA 2018 3.1 EAP (Ultimate Edition) + Open JDK 10.
- I raised a bug report with JetBrains for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202849

---

**Update 11/25/18**

There is a workaround for this issue without needing to rename the project's path:

- Run **Generate Javadoc** and let it fail.
- Click the link to the file **.../javadoc_args** shown in the **Javadoc** window.
- Copy and paste the content of the file **javadoc_args** into a text editor.
- Correct any characters that are misrepresented (e.g. change **M�ller** to **Müller**).
- Save the file using UTF-8 encoding, and the same absolute filename.
- Open a **Command Prompt** window.
- Copy the entire **javadoc.exe** command from the Javadoc window in Intellij IDEA and paste it to the **Command Prompt** window.
- Submit the line that was pasted. It will now work because the project's path is correctly specified in the file **javadoc_args**.

Comment: Well thank you for any circumstances that may arise and your answer! Okay seems to be logical, the only problem is: That means that I have to rename my user account and/or need administrative privileges to solve this issue?

Comment: @0x1C1B Yes, that would be the case for that specific project if your account name contains the character **ü**. And I can imagine that changing the account name might introduce some ugly unrelated problems! But there is an easy workaround for you: just create your Intellij IDEA projects in directories without **ü** in their path name, or are you required  to create projects in a specific location?

Comment: @0x1C1B Also, although I reported this as a bug, I suspect that there may be some existing solution because your problem is so basic it seems amazing that you are the first person to encounter the problem. Let's see what JetBrains have to say...

Comment: @0x1C1B I updated my answer to provide a workaround for this issue without needing to rename the project's path. It's still not a true solution, but since I think the problem is that JetBeans does not currently support UTF-8 encoding in the file that is passed to **javadoc.exe**, only they can provide a proper fix.

Comment: @0x1C1B I had forgotten about this problem, but I just verified that the bug fix from JetBrains works. (There are other issues associated with using **Tools > Generate Javadoc** in 2019.3, but I can no longer provoke your umlaut problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but in NetBeans, finally I could figure out the problem configuring correctly the Javadoc. I had "@author authorName1" and "@author authorName2", and no version tad. Finally, after replacing it for just one and going to **Run**, **Set project configuration** and **Customize**, there I changed the javadoc properties and set:

1. Uncheck @version tag
2. Check @author tag
3. Write a *Browser Title* without strange characters

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but in Apache Netbeans and the root of the problem was in the directory path. Have a look if your directory's path contains an accent(à,è,ì,ò or ù). In my case it was determinant to figure out the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Today (21-aug-2021) I tried to generate a javadoc but it failed.  The error message was:

**javadoc: error - cannot read Input length = 1**

In my case it referred to the length of the path to the file, which is shown below.

**D:\Tecnologia(ytrabajo)ysistemas26sep2020\misiontic2022\U El Bosque\UEB académico\Ciclo 2\Programación Básica\NetBProjects\R5DTO_DAOMVC_GUI**

So I shortened the path to the following:

**D:\Tecnologia(ytrabajo)ysistemas26sep2020\misiontic2022\NBProjects(m)\R5DTO_DAOMVC_GUI**

As one can see, this route is shorter than the first so NetBeans could access it and generate the javadoc.

Note: It is not possible that NetBeans could not read the location because of the following characters: é and á in the words académico and Básica that I used in the first file location.  Because, in that location, I tried to generate a JavaDoc in another project located there and NetBeans generated the Doc. So the error is more about the length of the path and the names of the files in the project.